# Test structure XML in PHPUnit

Tags: xml, unit-testing, xsd, phpunit, structure

I see assertEqualXMLStructure able to use test structure XML in PHPUnit. But I have problem with case: when 2 structure XML have different the number of children tags it failed although the structures is the same. Is there any way to do that with supporting from PHPUnit? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By editing assertEqualXMLStructure to ignore check the number of children of tags I solved my problem:

```
public static function assertEqualXMLStructure(DOMElement $expectedElement, DOMElement $actualElement, $checkAttributes = FALSE, $message = '') {
  self::assertEquals($expectedElement->tagName, $actualElement->tagName, $message);

  if ($checkAttributes) {
    self::assertEquals($expectedElement->attributes->length, $actualElement->attributes->length, sprintf('%s%sNumber of attributes on node "%s" does not match', $message, !empty($message) ? "\n" : '', $expectedElement->tagName));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $expectedElement->attributes->length; $i++) {
      $expectedAttribute = $expectedElement->attributes->item($i);
      $actualAttribute = $actualElement->attributes->getNamedItem($expectedAttribute->name);

      if (!$actualAttribute) {
        self::fail(sprintf('%s%sCould not find attribute "%s" on node "%s"', $message, !empty($message) ? "\n" : '', $expectedAttribute->name, $expectedElement->tagName));
      }
    }
  }

  PHPUnit_Util_XML::removeCharacterDataNodes($expectedElement);
  PHPUnit_Util_XML::removeCharacterDataNodes($actualElement);



  for ($i = 0; $i < $expectedElement->childNodes->length; $i++) {
    self::assertEqualXMLStructure($expectedElement->childNodes->item($i), $actualElement->childNodes->item($i), $checkAttributes, $message);
  }
}
```